# How to loop <li> in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to loop li tags on my view (cshtml), and I tried both "for and "foreach" loop, I debugged it, and it did the loop but it won't display the looped li tags. Why it won't show the looped li tags?

I passed my model to the view from controller, and inside the model are some error messages. I have debugged it, and it did carry those error messages, then I looped the error messages one by one using "for" and "foreach" loops (tried both), but the error messages are nowhere to be found on the view.

This is my view (cshtml):

```
                 @model Models.RootObject
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>

            <body>
                <input type="file" accept="application/pdf" id="fileAccept"/>
                <button type="submit" id="buttonSubmit">Submit</button>
                <ul id="showResultHere">
                    @{
                        if (Model != null)
                        {
                            for(int i=0; i<Model.Result.ErrorMessages.Count ; i++)
                            {
                                <li>Line @Model.Result.ErrorMessages[i].ToString()</li>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            </body>
            </html>

            <script src="/assets/scripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
            <script>

                $('#buttonSubmit').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    var file = document.getElementById("fileAccept").files[0];
                    formData.append("fileRequest", file);
                    formData.append("captcha", $("#captcha").val());

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Upload")",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formData,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert("All done!");
                        }
                        , error: function (err, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

                });

            </script>
```

Returning models to view from UploadController:

```
            if (isValid != true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < validationResults.Count; i++)
                {
                    result.ErrorMessages.Add(validationResults.ElementAt(i).ErrorMessage);
                }
                rootObject.Result = result;
                return View(rootObject);

                //return Json(validationResults);
            }
```

I expect the view to display the li tags with those error messages from the model.

Comment: Can you clarify "but the error messages are nowhere to be found on the view." Are they in the HTML output?

Comment: you have to render the messages inside Li tags.

Comment: @ScottHannen After looping, they won't show in the HTML output. It's baffling to me :/

Comment: @HiteshGaur how do I "render" the messages inside the li tags?

Comment: @hehehe you can use use @HTML.Raw(), if your error messages does not contain any encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the foreach like this:

```
@foreach(var errorMessage on Result.ErrorMessages)
{
    <li> Line @errorMessage.ToString() </li>
}
```

I´m not sure... but if it don´t work, try to add there at the top of your view:

```
@using System
```